# add a dot at 3rd position of the string with the help of regex in pandas

Tags: pandas, regex, string, dataframe

here is a sample table of the output I got while running this code

```
df['formatted_codes']=df['dx_code'].str.replace(r'(^\w{3}(?!$))',r'\1.',regex=True)
```

---

| dx_id | dx_code | formatted_codes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A00 | A00. |
| 2 | A000 | A00.0 |
| 3 | A001 | A00.1 |
| 4 | A009 | A00.9 |
| 5 | A01 | A01. |
| 6 | S92113 | S92.113 |
| 7 | S92113D | S92.113D |

---

but I want the '.' to apply only for characters more than 3 the output I want is like this

---

| dx_id | dx_code | formatted_codes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A00 | A00 |
| 2 | A000 | A00.0 |
| 3 | A001 | A00.1 |
| 4 | A009 | A00.9 |
| 5 | A01 | A01 |
| 6 | S92113 | S92.113 |
| 7 | S92113D | S92.113D |

---

so if anyone can help me with adjusting the regex code that would be helpful or if there is other way for add '.' at my desired location do tell

*****same question but different version*****

---

| dx_id | dx_code | formatted_codes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A00 | A00. |
| 2 | A000 | A00.0 |
| 3 | A00.1 | A00..1 |
| 4 | A00.9 | A00..9 |
| 5 | A01 | A01. |
| 6 | S92.113 | S92..113 |
| 7 | S92113D | S92.113D |

---

but I want the '.' to apply only for characters more than 3 the output I want is like this

---

| dx_id | dx_code | formatted_codes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A00 | A00 |
| 2 | A000 | A00.0 |
| 3 | A001 | A00.1 |
| 4 | A009 | A00.9 |
| 5 | A01 | A01 |
| 6 | S92113 | S92.113 |
| 7 | S92113D | S92.113D |

---

Comment: Your command does produce the expected output and not the incorrect one. `r'(^\w{3})'` would produce the incorrect output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```py
df['formatted_codes']=df['dx_code'].str.replace(r'\w{3}(?!$)', r'\g<0>.', regex=True)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IRjESY/1).

The `\w{3}(?!$)` regex finds three consecutive word chars that are not at the start of string and replaces the found text with the same text (the `\g<0>` backreference refers to the whole match value, no need for any extra capturing group around the whole pattern) *and* a dot char.

Comment: i have a bit of different situation now so could you look through the additional data added to question and give a solution for that situation

Comment: @SivaRamakrishnaKumar Try `r'^\w{3}\B'`

Comment: this code  `r'^\w{3}\B'` had not worked but when wrote I tried code `data['formatted_codes']=data['formatted_codes'].str.replace('\.\.','.',regex=True)` after applying the ur answer it worked

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.rstrip` to remove trailing dots from the `formatted_codes` column:

```py
df["formatted_codes"] = df["formatted_codes"].str.rstrip('.')
```

Comment: tried the code but not changes occured should in use inplace=
True

Comment: I disagree, because my answer assigns the column on the LHS to the rstrip version on the RHS.

Comment: maybe characters after '.' might be affecting  but the one that doesn't have characters after '.' has not been removed